# Can we use django orm to get a output like shown below

Tags: django, django-orm, django-1.9

```
[
    {'month_number':[1,2,3,4,5]},
    {'month_number_2':[6,6,8,8,8,10]}
]

class Test(Modelbase):
    student_id = models.IntegerField(null=True)
```

Above is the model and created_at is a default field to get the month_number.

I have used the below query to filter data, but using this we will have to loop again to differentiate for different month.

```
Model.objects.filter(created_at__month__gte=3).values(*['student_id','created_at'])
```

Can we do this using Django ORM in a single go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `groupby` of itertools:

```
from django.db.models import F, Func
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

query = (Model.objects.annotate(month=Func(F('created_at'), function='MONTH'))
                      .filter(month__gte=3)
                      .order_by('month')
                      .values('student_id','month'))

result = {
    m: [x['student_id'] for x in xs]
    for m, xs in groupby(query, itemgetter('month'))
}
```

We thus first generate a query where we construct an annotation: we annotate every `Model` instance with a `month` attribute that is the month of the `created_at` field.

Next we filter based on the fact that this `month` column is greater than or equal to `3`, next we order the queryset by that `month` (this is important for the `groupby` function that only works in case the items form groups based on the elemnt we want to group. We then perform a `values(..)` to make the query more efficient.

We then perform the `groupby(query, itemgetter('month'))` so we create chunks of elements with the same month. This creates an iterable of 2-tuples with `m` the month number, and `xs` an iterable of dictionaries that belong to that group.

We convert this iterable thus into a dictionary where `m` maps to the list of `student_id`s.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned this before, I'm using Django 1.9

Comment: @BharatBittu: the syntax is updated, and should probably work with 1.9.

Comment: Thank you for explaining. However, I'm getting the following response for the query - `SyntaxError: invalid syntax ('created_at'))filter.(month__gte=3)`

Comment: @BharatBittu: yes I made a typo. This should be fixed now.

Comment: Since this is Django 1.9, since there is no ExtractMonth, we will have to use Extract

Comment: @BharatBittu: aarghh... yes, you are right. Does `Extract` with `month` works?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172584/discussion-between-bharat-bittu-and-willem-van-onsem).